# sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to use SBT **0.13** with a SBT project which is currently under SBT **0.12.1**.

When running the project with SBT **0.13** I am getting the following `sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException` exception.

```
sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
        at sbt.Load$.incompatiblePlugins(Load.scala:621)
        at sbt.Load$.liftedTree1$1(Load.scala:609)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:608)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:564)
        at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:559)
        at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:547)
        at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:411)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
        at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
        at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:313)
        at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:265)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:261)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:252)
        at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:136)
        at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:40)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:434)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:176)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:80)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:69)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/Scoped$ListSetting
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:13)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugin(Load.scala:640)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Load.scala:637)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Load.scala:637)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.map(Stream.scala:376)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:637)
        at sbt.Load$.liftedTree1$1(Load.scala:608)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:608)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:564)
        at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:559)
        at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:547)
        at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:411)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
        at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
        at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:313)
        at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:265)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:261)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:252)
        at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:136)
        at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:40)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:434)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:176)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:80)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:69)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sbt.Scoped$ListSetting
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:13)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugin(Load.scala:640)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Load.scala:637)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadPlugins$1.apply(Load.scala:637)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.map(Stream.scala:376)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:637)
        at sbt.Load$.liftedTree1$1(Load.scala:608)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:608)
        at sbt.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:564)
        at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:559)
        at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:547)
        at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:411)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.Load$$anonfun$15$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:257)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:93)
        at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:92)
        at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:143)
        at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:313)
        at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:265)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:261)
        at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:252)
        at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:136)
        at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:40)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:434)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:428)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:176)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:87)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:80)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:69)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

What might be the cause of the exception? How to fix it?

Comment: I found the reason for this problem, a copy of sbt-start-script.jar was checked in the project/lib folder on my project, and this copy of sbt-start-script.jar was obviously meant for an older sbt version.

Comment: Could you please add the comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

a copy of sbt-start-script.jar was checked in the project/lib folder on my project, and this copy of sbt-start-script.jar was obviously meant for an older sbt version
Removing this jar file solved the problem.